# How to integrate Emoji's in web chat application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean, emoji

I am developing a web chat application (MEAN and Socket.io) in which requirements are to show up images in the way Slack/Web Whatsapp and other are showing similar like keyboard of our smartphones are showing. I have google it and i have found 
    http://emojione.com/developers/
    https://github.com/globaldev/angular-emoji-filter
    http://emoji.codes/
    https://github.com/twitter/twemoji

More of the articles about how to filter the string to find is user typed any emoji but none of are explaining how to integrate them in the app. Attaching a screenshot of what is required.

[image]